# Remove duplicates from array with duplicates having dependent values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array with duplicates values.
I need to remove duplicates out of it

```
this.list1 = [
               { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Maintenance' },
               { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Raw Material Plates and Profile' },
               { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Raw Material Plates and Profile' },
               { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Asset' },
               { item_id: 5, item_text: 'Asset' },
               .
               . 
               .
             ]
```

after removing duplicates,

```
this.list1 = [
               { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Maintenance' },
               { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Raw Material Plates and Profile' },
               { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Asset' },
               .
               . 
               .
             ]
```

And also item_id should be in order after removing duplicates.
How to do this in proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = this.list1.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.item_text === o.item_text)) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```